# Windows Forms, Value to be set has data type of Int32. Trying to throw exception for value range

Tags: c#, winforms

When setting property of a reference within one class I cannot throw my argument exception because of converting int to string. Confused as to how to solve this...

```
static private Int32 AttendeeRef;



static public string attendeeref
    {
        get
        {
            return AttendeeRef;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value <= 40000 && value >= 60000)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Attendee Ref must be between 40000 and 60000!");
            }
            AttendeeRef = value;
        }
    }
```

I've tried some converts and parse but all seems to fail.

Comment: the value of the property is string .. and you set to int32 - you can use int.Parse(value) to solve it

Comment: if condition  ( OR )  ||

Comment: If your backend variable is of type int why you declare the property of type string? This makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your getter should look like:

```
    return AttendeeRef.ToString();
```

And setter:

```
    AttendeeRef = Int32.Parse(value);
```

As for why, string and int are two different data types entirely. You need to explicitly cast between the two as the compiler doesn't inherently know how to do these conversions for you.

Answer (score 0):

This error is obvious. 
You are having int field and you are getting/setting in a string property. Better to change type from string to int.

```
static private Int32 AttendeeRef;

static public int attendeeref
{
    get
    {
        return AttendeeRef;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value <= 40000 && value >= 60000)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Attendee Ref must be between 40000 and 60000!");
        }
        AttendeeRef = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This error us obvious. Your code will never throw exception.

Comment: didn't get you?